# Simple way to draw RGB image data on screen in GTK

Tags: c, image, gtk, rgb

I have found some solutions on Google but they all seemed lengthy and overly complicated for what I need, so I decided to try to ask here.

My problem is simple, I want to draw some RGB 24-bit pixels on the screen.

In Qt, I would do it like this (x and y are the height and width of the image, data points to the 24-bit RGB pixels):

```
QImage graph((uchar *)data, x, y, QImage::Format_RGB888);
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(graph));
label->setFixedSize(x, y);
label->show();
```

Is there a similarly clean way to do this in C/GTK?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to load an image and draw into GTK or do you want to draw by yourself on a canvas area for example ?

Comment: I want to draw/display a data array containing x * y RGB 24-bit pixels.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for this would be using openCV and GTK+ together. First create an IplImage* (Its BRG by default and you have to convert it to RGB) and create a GdkPixbuf*. From the pixel buffer, you can set an image in a GtkImage*. I've blogged about it here : http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/2839808825/opencv-gtk-and-a-day

Hope this will be helpfull...

Comment: Sorry, but using another library is definitively not in line with my objective of finding a clean and simple solution (which is the purpose of this question, as I said, I found other ways to do it, but they are all quite unclean).